# vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument() is called even when there is no content changes or no document changes

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

`vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument()` is an API to detect changes in text document in vscode workspace. It fires every even separately. In my case, I need to catch only those events when file content is changed and the user saves it.

This is the closest [query](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/50344) as mine. As per this query, these are the event it should fire. Note 1 and 2 are fired simultaneously while 3 and 4 is fired during the document save action.

1. On content changes.(`changeEvent.contentChanges.length !==0`)
2. On document being dirty.(`changeEvent.document.isDirty === True`)
3. On document being saved.(`changeEvent.document.isDirty === False`)
4. Unnecessary event fire. (no new change)

However, the 4th event is fired unnecessarily. I checked there are no content changes or document changes. The 4th event is fired along with 3.

My question: Is this the right way to detect the saved event? If yes why the 4th event is fired?

Comment: Why not just use `workspace.onDidSaveTextDocument()` instead?

Comment: Yeah, I am using `workspace.onDidSaveTextDocument()` but do not understand the 4th time of event firing

Comment: In your question, you are saying that you are using ˋvscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument()ˋ (note the word "Change"). Is that a typo?

Comment: After your suggestion I USED workspace.onDidSaveTextDocument(). Nevertheless, I was curious about the unnecessary event firing in `vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument()`